# SQL Select with join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Hi guys i have table users:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `fotopath` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and table private_message:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `private_message` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_from` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reply_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `readed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_from` (`user_from`),
  KEY `user_to` (`user_to`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `private_message`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `private_message_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_from`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `private_message_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_to`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I want to Select (user_from,user_to,message,from_username,to_username,readed,date)
I have tried this:

```
SELECT P.user_from,P.user_to,P.message,P.readed,P.date,U.username as from_username,D.username as to_username 
FROM private_message as P JOIN users as U ON(P.user_from=U.id) JOIN users as D ON(P.user_to=D.id) 
GROUP BY to_username,from_username
```

and it gives me

```
user_from|user_to|message|from_username|to_username|readed|date  
    1    |   2   |  asdf |   Admin     |   Baski   |   0  | 2014-06-22 12:00:16  
    2    |   1   |  asdf |   Baski     |   Admin   |   0  | 2014-06-22 12:02:16  
    3    |   1   |  asdf |   Smrdis    |   Admin   |   0  | 2014-06-22 12:02:16
```

I need table like this:

```
user_from|user_to|message|from_username|to_username|readed|date  
    2    |   1   |  asdf |   Baski     |   Admin   |   0  | 2014-06-22 12:02:16  
    3    |   1   |  asdf |   Smrdis    |   Admin   |   0  | 2014-06-22 12:12:16
```

Simply I when i'm selecting i only know my user_id. I need select all messages sended to the user or sended by the user and group it by the id of second person (can be sender or recevier).  I can't simply group it by user_to or user_from because you can only send message and don' get response. Can somebody help me with this ?

Comment: i dont see your `user_id` in both tables?

Answer (score 0):

you can just add this line of WHERE.

```
WHERE U.id = ...
GROUP BY to_username,from_username
```

Comment: I can add "Where P.user_from = ID or P.user_to = ID" but i would no group it properly it would group messages between each user into 2 rows not 1 as I want to

Comment: you said you know just `user_id` but you have no `user_id` so i guessed its id in your users table

Comment: I mean that i know ID of the user which I want to display messages between other users.